# Compiling x64 on 32bits version of windows (Teamcity)

Tags: c#, .net, msbuild, 64-bit, teamcity

Our Teamcity agent is running on a 32bits OS for now and this was not an issue up until now (we now have an x64 applications to build in there).

I heard its possible to compile x64 applications on a 32bit OS but I've never did it. What would be the step required to have Teamcity build a specific project in x64 - Ideally using MSBuild?

When I set my project's MSBuild property "Run Platform" to x64 my agent give me the following warning: "Unmet requirements: DotNetFramework4.0_x64 exists"

As a side note: we will eventually move the agent to a 64bits OS but I would like a short term solution.

Comment: Never explicitly select x64 as the platform target, always AnyCPU.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think the `Run Platform` for MSBuild in TeamCity is for what version of MSBuild to use, it's looking for MSBuild.exe in the `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319` folder, when you're on a 32-bit version of Windows, and that framework isn't installed.  However, the 32-bit version of MSBuild can invoke the C# Compiler that can still produce x64 assemblies, even on your 32-bit machine.

What you want to do is do a `Run Platform` for x86, but pass `/property:Platform=x64` as one of your commands.  If you don't have a x64 Configuration, you may considering trying to pass it `/property:Platform="Any CPU"`.  However, Any CPU would only be guaranteed to work if all the assemblies you reference in your project are set the Any CPU as well.  Alternative, you can create a custom configuration where all your assemblies are specified x64, and pass that via command line to MSBuild.

Keep in mind if any of your projects are C++, you will need to make sure you have the x64 compilers installed, as I don't think they're installed by default.

Comment: That's what I was looking for. Except instead of /Property:Configuration=x64 it was /Property:Platform=x64

Comment: Oh yes, that's my bad, I'll update the answer.  Configuration is for Release/Debug, Platform specifies CPU.